# How to loop through my array matrix and create an object containing items by their category

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

So I created the following:

I made this matrix array, each nested array has objects:

```
[
  [
    { category: 'tech', product: "iPhone X", price: 320 },
    { category: 'food', product: "Cheerios", price: 5 },
  ],

  [
    { category: 'food', product: "Snickers", price: 1.5 },
    { category: 'tech', product: "Air Pods", price: 129 },
  ],  

]
```

Then, I created this function that loops through the array matrix:

```
function sortProducts (matrix) {
  for (x=0;x<matrix.length;x++) {      
      for (y=0;y<matrix[x].length;y++){ 
         console.log(matrix[x][y]);     
    }  
  }
}
```

Now, Im just trying to figure out how to create and return a new object containing the products sorted by their category like this:

```
{
 tech:  [ { tech product }, { tech product } ],
 food:  [ { food product }, { food product } ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten and reduce...

```js
const data = [
  [
    { category: 'tech', product: "iPhone X", price: 320 },
    { category: 'food', product: "Cheerios", price: 5 },
  ],

  [
    { category: 'food', product: "Snickers", price: 1.5 },
    { category: 'tech', product: "Air Pods", price: 129 },
  ],  
];

const flat = arr => arr.reduce((acc, el) => acc.concat(el),[]);

function sortProducts(matrix) {
  return flat(matrix).reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let cat = obj.category;
    if (!acc[cat]) acc[cat] = [];
    acc[cat].push(obj);
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(sortProducts(data))
```

`flat()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)) **note the availability section in that doc** promotes objects contained in nested arrays to the top level of the outer array. (We don't need the column structure to index by category). `reduce()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) just iterates that flattened array, passing an object between iterations. The object category is used as the key, and the values are arrays. `acc[cat].push(obj);` pushes the object to the array whose key is the category.

Comment: How can I implement this code into this function? Im not familiar with this style - flatten and reduce                           function sortProducts (matrix) {                                                                             }

Comment: @NikoNota - do you mean wrap the logic in a function with the OP signature?  Pls see edit.

Comment: Im having issues compiling this code for some reason. Do you happen to know an alternative way to solving this? I dont think my system is able to process flat & reduce.

Comment: I just need to return an object with two properties - 'Tech' & 'Food' , each having products sorted by category

Comment: @NikoNota - What does the error say?

Comment: It states 'TypeError: matrix.flat is not a function
    at sortProducts (test.js:3:17)
    at Context.it (test.js:64:28)', and that it should return an object with two properties "tech" and "food", each having products sorted by category.

Comment: its not recognizing matrix.flat because it seems to be an inbuilt function in Underscore.js library

Comment: @NikoNota - flat is new-ish, and it appears not supported in your environment.  It is in underscore, if you're using that, but it's easy enough to roll our own, as I did in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

**we can achieve this way too**

```js
const data = [
  [
    { category: 'tech', product: "iPhone X", price: 320 },
    { category: 'food', product: "Cheerios", price: 5 },
  ],

  [
    { category: 'food', product: "Snickers", price: 1.5 },
    { category: 'tech', product: "Air Pods", price: 129 },
  ],  
];

const fun = (ar)=>{
 var obj ={}
const mix = ar.flatMap((el ,i)=> el)
for (let[i, e] of Object.entries(mix)){
  let sep = e.category
!obj[sep] ? obj[sep]=[e] : obj[sep].push(e)
}
 return obj
}
console.log(fun(data))
```